# Get the parent div whose css property is not display none

Tags: jquery, css

Get the parent div whose `css` property is not display none

```
$(this).closest("div").not("css","display:none")
```

I tried the above it doesn't seem to work

Comment: `$(this).closest('div:visible');`

Comment: Is the CSS property (`display: none`) set by a class rule or through the `style` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)**

```
$(this).closest("div:visible")
```

---

or **[`:hidden`](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)**

```
$(this).closest("div:not(:hidden)")
// or
// $(this).closest("div").not(":hidden")
```